# Show storage engine config in mongosh

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-shell, wiredtiger

I've created a collection (in Java) with storage engine options where the block compressor should be `zstd`. How can I verify that [.storageEngineOptions()](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.6/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/client/model/CreateCollectionOptions.html#storageEngineOptions%28org.bson.conversions.Bson%29) worked as expected? Is it possible through `mongosh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `db.collection.stats()`. You will get a large output, we are interested in `creationString` key, which is a large string, something like this:

```
creationString: 'access_pattern_hint=none,allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),assert=(commit_timestamp=none,durable_timestamp=none,read_timestamp=none,write_timestamp=off),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=snappy
```

The compression algorithm will be a part of this string.